# Javascript not un-clicking button with link

Tags: javascript

Newish to javascript, but I do't know why the below is not working. I am trying to use javascript to make a link become active after a button has become clicked.

The user clicks a button that updates the HTML, changes the class and adds a html link. The code works the first time -- the HTML is updated correctly. However if the user decides to un-click the button nothing happens.

Javascript:

```
function agree() {
  let agreement = document.getElementById("agreement");
  let agree = document.getElementById("agree");

  agree.onclick = () => {
    if (agree.value === true) {
      agreement.innerHTML = `
             <button id="agree" class="agree--no" value="false"></button>I agree
                  <div class="btn--no-schedule">
                    <a href="#" > No SCHEDULE  </a>
                </div> `
    } else {
        agreement.innerHTML = `
            <button id="agree" class="agree--checked" value="true"><i class="fas fa-lg fa-check-square"></i></button>I agree
          <div class="btn--agree-schedule">
                <a href="http://google.com" > yes SCHEDULE  </a>
       </div> `
    }
  }
};
```

HTML

```
<div id="agreement">
  <button id="agree" class="agree--no" value="false"></button>I agree
    <div class="btn--no-schedule">
      <a href="#" > SCHEDULE  </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried

`<button onclick=“agree();” id="agree" class="agree--no" value="false"></button>`

but get a type error agree() is not a function.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can try to use the `onmouseup` event. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
function ChangeContent(checkbox) {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("schedule-agreement")[0];
  (checkbox.checked) ? el.innerText = "No SCHEDULE": el.innerText = "Yes SCHEDULE"
}
```

```html
<div id="agreement">
  <input type="checkbox" onchange="ChangeContent(this)"> I agree
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="schedule-agreement">SCHEDULE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

First of all, add a change event listener to the input checkbox. Then, whenever it is run, check if it is checked. If it is, change the link's `innerText` to "No SCHEDULE", otherwise, change it to "Yes SCHEDULE".

If you *need* to use a button, then I would recommend adding a `click` event listener (or an `onclick` inline event listener), and changing the link `innerText` ONLY - not the whole HTML.

In that case, here's a separate demo:

```js
var isChecked = false

function ChangeContent() {
  isChecked = !(isChecked)
  if (isChecked) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("agree")[0].innerText = "✔️ I agree"
    document.getElementsByClassName("schedule-agreement")[0].innerText = "No SCHEDULE"
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("agree")[0].innerText = "❌ I agree"
    document.getElementsByClassName("schedule-agreement")[0].innerText = "Yes SCHEDULE"
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="agreement">
  <button class="agree" onclick="ChangeContent()">I agree</button>
  <div class="btn--no-schedule">
    <a href="#" class="schedule-agreement">SCHEDULE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors here.

First, the **click** event is lost when you reset the agreement's innerHTML, second, `agree.value` is a string, and thus will never be "=== true".

There are multiple ways of fixing it. One way is changing the innerHTML part so the event isn't lost. Also, changing the condition to `=== 'true'`

Like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="agreement">
  <button id="agree" class="agree--no" value="false"></button>I agree
    <div id="schedule-btn" class="btn--no-schedule">
      <a href="#" > SCHEDULE  </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function agree() {
  const agreeBtn = document.getElementById("agree");
  const scheduleBtn = document.getElementById("schedule-btn");

  agreeBtn.onclick = () => {
    if (agreeBtn.value === "true") {
      agreeBtn.value = false;
      scheduleBtn.innerHTML = `
          <div class="btn--no-schedule">
            <a href="#" > No SCHEDULE  </a>
          </div>
        `;
    } else {
      agreeBtn.value = true;
      scheduleBtn.innerHTML = `
          <div class="btn--agree-schedule">
            <a href="http://google.com" > yes SCHEDULE  </a>
          </div>
        `;
    }
  };
}
```

Edit: I tried to alter your code as little as possible